# jQuery file upload allow only doc files

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I am using the [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)  plugin.

I want to upload only files with the extensions like .doc, .docx, .pdf. So can someone tell me how to allow the plugin only to upload .doc, .docx, .pdf files. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I've the same problem, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `acceptFileTypes` option like,

```
var acceptFileTypes =/^application\/(pdf|msword)$|^doc$|^docx$/i;
```

Read [more about options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['doc','docx','pdf']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the accept attribute on the input tag

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter at options of the plugin for this purpose.

```
 options: {
   acceptFileTypes: 'File type not allowed',
}
```

The explanation is here : 
[fileupload-validate.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=file%20type)

Answer (score 0):

search the line in the file: server/php/UploadHandler.php

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i'
```

Add to the end, thus:

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$/i'
```

Comment: This seems right.  Why is there a down vote?  I am trying to do this as well...

Answer (score 0):

Here is two way to do this:

> First:

```
$('#file').on( 'change', function() {
   myfile= $( this ).val();
   var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
   if(ext=="docx" || ext=="doc"){
       alert(ext);
   } else{
       alert(ext);
   }
});
```

> In alert box showing you actual file type `alert(ext);`
>
> Second:

> The extensions should start with a dot `"."`